# What does top right corner value in Fast Fourier Transformation (FFT) show?

Tags: matlab

In case to apply `fft2`on matrix we get a matrix with sum of all matrix elements on left top corner but a number also show on top right corner.What does it show ?

Here is function i applied [image: Click here to view]

And here is result it generates and the value at top right corner i am asking about
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The first row is the 1-D FFT of the sum of each column of `b`. That is, if you do `fft(sum(b))` you would get the first row of `bf`.
If you look at the definition of DFT you can see that the `N/2` bin is given by:

```
X[N/2] = sum( x[n]exp(2*pi*j*N/2*n/N) ) =  sum( x[n]exp(2*pi*j/2*n) ) = sum(x[n]*(-1)^n)
```

So that means that the top-right corner you marked is the sum of all odd columns of `b` minus the sum of all even columns of `b`.